# why nodejs express server return 302 when i use post?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ajax, rest, express

I am creating a signup and login system. I get a form html page in GET request which works fine but then when I use post to post my data the server return 302 in the chrome inspect and the request type is xhr given that I didnt say redirect or any code that tell the browser to do that. I really need help in that.

this is the server file

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var signupRouter = require('./routes/signup.js');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/signup', signupRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
}); 

app.listen(3000, "localhost", function() {
  console.log("server started listening on port 3000");
});

module.exports = app;
```

and this is the router file

```
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('11212112');

  res.render('signup', { title: 'signup section' });
});

router.post('create', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('fefffefefef');
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.send('lfffff');
});

module.exports = router;
```

and this is the javascript on browser

```
        $.post("http://localhost:3000/signup/create",
            {
                name: "Donald Duck",
                city: "Duckburg"
            },
            function (data, status) {
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });

    }
```

**NOTE**

the alert is not appearing at the post callback i only see 302 at chrome inspect

**UPDATE**

this is the image of the postman testing the url

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's `createError`?

Comment: you just pointed me to a function that i dont know , i took this script from building a node express tutorial as a starter , do you think it is the issue ? what i know as commented is that it handles the error of 404 maybe with a custom html page

Comment: create error is a function that handles the 404 see first line in the script i used `var createerror`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to needing to enable `mergeParams` in your router declaration in your routing file

```
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
```

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.router

> mergeParams   -- Preserve the req.params values from the parent router.
>   If the parent and the child have conflicting param names, the child’s
>   value take precedence.

Example implementation from a generic todo repo I made : https://github.com/jongear/async-api-example-js/blob/master/src/routes/todoRoutes.js#L4

Answer (score -1):

Please change your post route like below :

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('fefffefefef');
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.send('lfffff');
});
```

You have missed a slash.

Slash **'/'** is important since your BASEURL is `http://localhost:3000` and not `http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: stil the same .

Comment: and the weird part is that the console function not printing anything , which might tell me that the function is not called at all since the response code is different and the console not printing

Comment: Have you attempted url in postman? with return res.json('something'); to check?

Comment: 302 found returned .. check my updated question with the image

Comment: Can you shift the get list route below the create route and check it?